# Server Push using java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlet-3.0, server-push

I am trying to create a simple example of server Push using Java.

As in the server push client will send request only once to the server. The server keeps the HTTP request alive for that client and keeps on sending the updated data to the client. Please let me know how to proceed or can give me some initial idea for this.

Also let me know if we need to use Servlet 3.0 or JMS for this...

Is it possible using Servlet3.0 and HTML5?

Comment: r u trying to implement something like chatting?? Better use XMPP for that

Comment: I just want to develop some basic example to implement server push functionality. I want that i will request the server once and then server will keep sending the updated data...

Answer (score 5):

You can use the new [websocket](http://www.websocket.org/) specification which is made to maintain a full-duplex channel for client-server communication based on sockets so both instances can still send data at any time (Here come your server push based on some events or whatever logic).

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-websockets-jsr-356-jetty) you can inspire from.

BR.

Comment: Thanks for the above tutorial. I dont want to use any java framework as i am not familiar... May b some core java+HTML5.

Comment: The Websocket is not a java framework but a Java API defined in JSR-356.